# Unit Testing Scenario

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a method that takes the users ldap roles and evaluates each of his/her roles against a list called "ValidRoles" in the websites web.config file. We will assume  that the users roles will remain the same accross different users for the purposes of this test.

Now I would like to trick the method into taking in a different list (rather than the one in my web.config) to compare against when I run my unit test. **How can I do this ?** I am new to unit testing. I appreciate any suggestions. The method I am testing, the ValidRoles from the web.config, and an existing unit test I have are shown below.

```
   private bool IsValidClaimStationRoles()
    {
        foreach (string role in RoleList)
        {
            if (role != null)
            {
                if (ValidRoleList.Contains(role.ToUpper()))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
```

//Valid roles from web.config

```
 <add key="ValidRoles" value="C-2,CP-1,CM-1,CIS-1,CID-1"/>
```

//Unit test

```
       [TestMethod()]
    [DeploymentItem("ClaimsDocMgmtLinkWeb.dll")]
    public void IsValidClaimStationRolesTest_Negative()
    {

        AuthenticateUser_Accessor target = new AuthenticateUser_Accessor(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        target.CreateTicket();
        bool expected = false; 
        bool actual;



        actual = target.IsValidClaimStationRoles();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    }
```

Comment: Look into mocking(MOQ) or faking (Fakes). This allows you to fake certain objects, methods, that are necessary to test your methods.

Comment: are the tests in a different project? typically the test project can have its own config file

Comment: Yes. Actually the tests are in a different .NET solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your unit test scenario here will fail mostly since `RoleList` won't be present. Actual method validates against a list of roles which is present in `RoleList` collection.

You should refactor your function and have it accepts a `RoleList` parameter and then you can pass fake roles and test your method. what I am exactly talking about it `Dependency Injection` here.

```
   private bool IsValidClaimStationRoles(RoleList roles)
    {
      // do processing code
    }
```

Comment: Hi Raul. Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I don't want to touch the code in the method I'm testing if I don't have to.